# How to install packages locally?

Tags: linux, debian

Background: I have a kubuntu laptop right now that I can't use wirelessly, i.e. I haven't got wireless assistant installed. But I have a windows laptop that I can download the debian packages seperately on a USB memory stick.

How do I install a debian package on the computer locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the USB stick mounted:

```
dpkg --install /path/to/foo_VVV-RRR.deb
```

(where fooVVV-RRR.deb is the package's file name)

You can find more commands at the [Debian GNU/Linux FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkgtools.en.html).

Side note: this is from the command line.  I'm not sure how to get synaptic to do it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :) You can also call it with dpkg -i /path/to/foo_VVV-RRR.deb

Comment: apt works at the repository (group of packages) level.
dpkg works with individual packages.

I've a summary of the important commands here:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/packaging.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're not a command line fan, double-clicking on the .deb files in the file manager should launch a package installer.  Has exactly the same effect as `dpkg -i` of course.

Comment: If it's kubuntu, it's most probably konqueror or dolphin, not nautilus.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered this after the fact. I fancy the command line more when the computer I work with is slow. :) Upvoted.